# How to configure multiple bindings for the same child type

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I'm new to Java and I'm jumping right in the deep end and using Guice in a project but I can't work out how to bind different values to a constructor based on what parent object the current object will be injected into.

In my code I want to be able to pass in the path to some XSLT files in the constructor of the MessageTransformer but these should be different depending on what it's being injected into.

```
public class MessageTransformer {
    public MessageTransformer(String XsltRequestPath, String XsltReplyPath {
        ....
    }
}

public class SomeClassThatTransformsMessages {
    public SomeClassThatTransformsMessages(Transformer transformer) {
        ....
    }

public class SomeOtherClassThatTransformsMessages {
    public SomeOtherClassThatTransformsMessages(Transforms transformer)    {
        ....
    }
}
```

So if I was doing it manually I'm trying to recreate the following:

```
variable1 = new SomeClassThatTransformsMessages      (new Transformer("fileA", "fileB"));
variable2 = new SomeOtherClassThatTransformsMessages (new Transformer("fileC", "fileD"));
```

I don't think I can use the @Named attribute on the transformer but i can possibly use that on the parent classes but not sure how to wire up the files.

I've looked at all the bindings help but none appear to match.

Thanks

Comment: Your syntax is slightly wrong for `Some[Other]ClassThatTransformsMessages`, I'm assuming those are supposed to be constructors?

Comment: Yes sorry was just trying to get the point over with the minimum code and messed it up! I think private modules might be what I need just can't work out how to do it.

Comment: I feel like `bind(Transformer.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("foo")).toInstance(new Transformer(...));` is what you need.

Comment: Possibly, I come from C# and most of the containers do convention over configuration so "hard coding" the construction into the toInstance method doesn't seem right but it will certainly be nicer than the way I've been going.

Comment: I agree that the hardcoding smells bad.  You can do `toProvider(FooTransformerProvider.class)` to factor it out, or use an `@Provides` method instead.  Alternatively, if you want to inject `Transformer` directly, you have the robot legs problem which is talked about [here](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#how-do-i-build-two-similar-but-slightly-different-trees-of-objects).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, could you post a slightly longer SSCCE of the Guiceless version and your Guicey attempt?  It sounds like maybe you need assisted injection and/or a multibinder, but I still need a better understanding of what you're doing.